# Python - counting the nonzero elements in pandas columns in a time series for each quarter

Tags: python-3.x

example I have a data frame in time series format. 
I want an output column "C" that counts the non zero elements for each quarter.
I have tried to use pd.rolling(3).count, but i need to customize it somehow or use a function.

```
A         B      C
time1     5          
time2     0 
time3     3      2
time4     4   
time5     9
time6     4      3
time7     2
time8     0
time9     0      1
time10    3
time11    4
time12    7      3
```